# How to debug a c# activex

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, activex

I have a c# project that generate my activex component.
The debug project is a simple web application that call the registered dll.

Javascript debug points and exceptions works fine.

How can i catch debug points and exception in the ActiveX c# project?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a web application.  Project + Properties, Debug tab.  Select "external" and specify the command that starts your browser.  Set breakpoints and press F5.

Comment: If i use the Library project as starting project with "start external program" = iexplorer and "Command line arguments" = testPage.html i still can't load debug points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I would attach debugger to the process which calls the component. In visual studio: Debug/Attach to process...

You can also put Debug.Assert(false) in the place where you want to stop to generate a debug prompt. Sometimes it works.

Comment: I have tried but the exception I thrown in the activex just stick to the Script in the html, not the c# code.

Comment: Sometimes you can put Debug.Assert(false) to generate a debug prompt. Not always works though.

Comment: Strange, i know is some kind of dirty configuration in my machine, but with that Debug.Assert(false) I was able to sink the debug point in another ad hoc visual studio 2012 debug session. Can i Edit your answer to match my solution and mark like a valid answer?

Comment: Instead of `Debug.Assert` you can use `Debugger.Launch()`, which will open the debugger selection screen.